# How do I design a LinkedIn plugin in OpenCart 3.0.3.1? Can I get the flow to design this plugin?

Tags: opencart-3

I want to design my own Login with LinkendIn module and want to publish in marketplace in OpenCart 3.0.3.1. Can I get proper flow to start.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow community. Please read the post on how to ask questions in stackoverflow - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Just read how... https://www.linkedin.com/developers/

Comment: Thanks, I also want to how to start coding part for this plugin in Opencart

Comment: This isn't a technical question, this is a whole project. You should either develop it yourself or pay a developer to build it for you.